# Is there a way of abstracting parameter passing to a C function?

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm implementing a system call handler which receives on the stack the number of the system call and its arguments. The functions which deal with system calls have different return types, different numbers of arguments and different argument types.

I've abstracted the function being called by defining a `struct` containing function pointers, to which I'm passing the system call number.

I have no idea however how to abstract parameter passing, meaning:

a)parameter conversion

b)different number of parameters

c)holding/not holding the return value

The only ideas I've had so far involve a serious amount of code duplication.
Is there a way of doing this and avoiding switch statements as much as possible?

Comment: Exactly how mad at me would you be if I suggested writing the function that makes the call in assembler?  Other than that I think you will have to have a line of C code that calls a function pointer with that particular permutation of typed parameters, for each possible permutation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your asking... but are you looking to write a variadic function?

Comment: Are you calling a system call from userspace, or calling into userspace from a kernel function?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible routes for you:

1. Use a C variadic function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C Here one of the early parameters specifies what kind of additional parameters are to be expected (much like in `printf`).
2. Use a 'type of call' parameter, and a `void *` parameter, the latter which is cast appropriately depending on the type of call.
3. Use a pointer to a struct, which contains the type of call, and either a `void *`, or a `union` or a zero length byte array (again which will ultimately be cast to the correct `struct`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at how e.g. Linux does it. System calls user-side are handled with a set of macros, one for each number or parameters (luckily, this isn't Windows with its gargantuan argument lists). See `syscall(2)` for some ideas. Perhaps also check out the BSD way.

Essentially, in Linux what happens (on i686, haven't really looked into x86_64) is that the system call number (this defines the number and types of arguments) gets passed in a register, a few other arguments in other registers, and exceptionally some on the stack. The system call number is used to index into a table of functions to do the dirty work after setting up the right arguments for a call.